# Discord Bot Command_not_work

Tags: python, discord.py

***My console dont show any errors, the slash commands works, but when I type "!dog", it should return "dog", but nothing happen.***

'''

```
import discord
import random
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

id_do_servidor = my_server_id  



class client(discord.Client):
  bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=discord.Intents.all()) 

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())

    self.synced = False  

  async def on_ready(self):
    await self.wait_until_ready()
    if not self.synced:  
      await tree.sync(
        guild=discord.Object(id=id_do_servidor)
      ) 
      self.synced = True
    print(f"{self.user.name} is online.")


aclient = client()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(aclient)
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='dog')
async def sapo(ctx):
    await ctx.send('dog')


@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=id_do_servidor),
              name='test',
              description='test')  
async def slash2(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_message(f"Working!",
                                          ephemeral=True)
  
  
aclient.run(
  'my_bot_token')
```

'''

If someone know a solution, please help me, thanks for your atention.

Answer (score 0):

You have both a discord client (`aclient`), and the bot object (`bot`), in your code, but you only run the bot on `aclient` (and the commands are registered to the `bot` object, so hence do not work). You cannot use both a client and bot object at the same time. In your instance, change `class client(discord.Client):` to `class client(commands.Bot):` and change the constructor to have the parameters you've used with the bot: `super().__init__((command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default())`

Then, simply replace any more references in your code using `bot` to `aclient`, ie:
`@bot.command(name='dog')` -> `@aclient.command(name='dog')`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'

Comment: Fixed the error - `commands` is from the import `from discord.ext import commands`